# Best way to show child modal within a map?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bootstrap-4, reactstrap

Link to project: https://repl.it/repls/PrudentAptSystems

I have `App.js` and `PageFive.js`. `App.js` contains an array:

```
state = {
    boxes: [
      {
        cbIndex: "cb1",
        name: "Bob"
      },
      {
        cbIndex: "cb2",
        name: "Daniel"
      },...
```

...and `PageFive.js` contains a map function that displays boxes:

```
{this.props.boxes.map((box, id, image, moduleId) => (
            <div key={id} className="col-md-6 col-lg-4">
              <div className="sample-container">
                <div className="container">
                 <div className="row">
                  <div className="col-md-12">
                    <ul>
                      <li>
                        <input
                          type="checkbox"
                          id={box.cbIndex}...
```

Screen shot:

[image]

I'd like to have a different modal appear for each button click ("Info").

As it appears currently, everything is working as it should, except only the last modal item (there are 6) is showing no matter which "Info" button I select:

[image]

I'm using Reactstrap, and the rest of my code looks like this:

(PageFive.js):

```
class PageFive extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      modal: false
    };

    this.toggle = this.toggle.bind(this);
  }

  toggle() {
    this.setState({
      modal: !this.state.modal
    });
  }
```

JSX for the button and modal, which is nested inside the map function above:

```
<Button color="danger" onClick={this.toggle.bind(this, moduleId)}>
{this.props.buttonLabel}
</Button>
<Modal
isOpen={this.state.modal}
toggle={this.toggle.bind(this, moduleId)}
className={this.props.className}
>
<ModalHeader toggle={this.toggle}>
    <p>hi </p>
</ModalHeader>
<ModalBody>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
    adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor
    incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
</ModalBody>
<ModalFooter>
    <Button color="primary" onClick={this.toggle}>
    Do Something
    </Button>{" "}
    <Button
    color="secondary"
    onClick={this.toggle}
    >
    Cancel
    </Button>
</ModalFooter>
```

Is there a way to do this without using portals or Redux?

Comment: Add a property in your boxes object for each box to store the modal display and toggle the model according to that.

Comment: @suhailc Thank you. Could you please provide an example of what you mean?

Comment: can you duplicate your application here https://repl.it/languages/reactjs

Comment: @suhailc Here you go! https://repl.it/repls/PrudentAptSystems

Comment: Edited your project. check now. Didn't used the method i mentioned above, used another way to toggle  https://repl.it/repls/SeveralTragicStaff  @bunnycode

Comment: @suhailc This works! Thank you so much. If you feel like posting your solution as an answer, I'll mark it as correct. Thank you again, spent all day on this and was spinning in circles. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than toggle the modals by using true or false in state, use the modals id to keep track of which modal is opened. I have edited your project check in https://repl.it/repls/SeveralTragicStaff